# prove $f_n$ uniformly converges to zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Good afternoon!

I'm trying to solve this problem:

"Let $f_n:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a sequence of functions defined as $f_n(x)=\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$. Prove that $f_n$ uniformly converges to zero".

I am aware that I must proove that, given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $n>n_0 \Rightarrow |\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|< \varepsilon$. From now on, how to proceed to find $n_0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\left|\sin(y) \right| \le 1$$ for all real $y$

Comment: Hello, Henry. Thanks for writing. I have already had this idea, but $|sin(nx)|\le 1$ doesn't imply $|\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le \varepsilon $ because it could be $|\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}| \le \varepsilon \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: What if $n \gt \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$?

Comment: I'm afraid it is also impossible, because: $|\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|\le \varepsilon \rightarrow \frac{sin^2(nx)}{n} \le \varepsilon^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \le \frac {n}{sin^2(nx)}$. But $\frac{1}{sin^2(nx)} \ge 1$.

Comment: $\left|\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}\right| \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \lt \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}}} = \varepsilon$ for all $n \gt \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$, i.e. $\left|\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}\right|  \lt  \varepsilon$ for all $n \gt \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$|\sin nx|\leq 1$. Solve the inequality 
$$\frac1{\sqrt {n_0}}<\varepsilon$$

Then, the path should be clear.